# Display data from two tables by grouping in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new in php field. I have created 2 tables in Mysql 1.Group 2. Event. 
goup_id is primary key in group and its foreign key in event.

I want to display events which is in specific group. 
Example : Group1 
          Event 1
          Event 2

```
      Group2 
      Event 3 
      Event 4 etc
```

In this way, first group title and then list of events in that group will come. I want to select data from 2 different table.

Please help!! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM Event as e LEFT JOIN Group as g on g.group_id=e.group_id ORDER BY e.group_id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
    $currGroup = -1;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       if($row['groupName']!=$currGroup){
         $currGroup = $row['groupName'];
         echo $currGroup."\n";
       }
       echo $row['eventName']."\n";
    }
}`

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks for the quick response. Code is working fine. But it is displaying list of group and events in one line, even if use "\n". Please give any suggestion for that. Thanks

Comment: If this is HTML, try replacing the \n with br tags. Add any additional HTML tags around it for flavor and style.